# Area under curve for multiple groups in R

Tags: r, integration, area, curve

I have seven different groups measuring fluorescence over 20 hours. I have made the graphs, and I would now like to calculate the area under the curves of the different groups.
A subset of my data looks like this:

```
Condition Hour N Fluorescence
0 J/cm2    0 2       1537.0
0 J/cm2    1 2       2343.0
0 J/cm2    2 2       1907.0
0 J/cm2    3 2       1632.5
0 J/cm2    4 2       2864.0
0 J/cm2    5 2       3518.5
TBHP       0 2      11231.5
TBHP       1 2      11144.0
TBHP       2 2      11068.5
TBHP       3 2      10881.5
TBHP       4 2      10662.0
TBHP       5 2      10530.0
```

I have read a lot of different threads on the same subject, but it's always with either only one group or with different columns, and I do not know how to translate that to my data.

Right now I am using the trapz function from the zoo package:

```
AUC=trapz(Hour, Fluorescence)
```

But that only gives me the overall area, or I would have to do the groups individually, which I would prefer not to do.

I would be happy to use a different function or whatever, but my preferred outcome would be something like this:

```
Condition AUC
0 J/cm2    0 
TBHP       1
```

Or set up so I could do a barplot of the different areas.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your dataframe is called `dat` and the `trapz()`-function only requires one parameter you could try:

```
aggregate(dat$Fluorescence,by=list(dat$Condition),FUN=zoo::trapz)
```

(I haven't 100% tried out this call, but the `aggregate()` function might at least point you into the right direction (I hope...))

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using 'aggregate(dat$Fluorescence,by=list(dat$Condition),FUN=pracma::trapz)' as I must have remembered the package wrong.

Comment: Great to hear! Yes, I was wondering a bit whether `trapz` is part of `zoo`-package... But I do know `pracma` as well... Good luck with your analysis!